# Замена содержимого тегов <price> xml файла

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Как с помощью регулярки и php-функций заменить содержимое всех тегов  xml файла на это же содержимое, но умноженное на 32? Нужно для импорта товаров в Woocommerce, а там стоит цена в долларах. Если есть решение на js, то тоже не откажусь.

Comment: а разве js умеет перезаписывать файлы ?

Comment: не умеет)сглупил)

Comment: пунктов много ?

Comment: больше 1600 цен надо поменять

Comment: я извеняюсь конечно ... но лучше на фрилансе .. или ждите ..мож кто сделает

Answer (score 0):

С помощью встроенного парсера в JS

```js
var xmldoc, parser, xmlroot;
var rawxmldoc = 
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"+
"<root>"+
"<price>"+
"200"+
"</price>"+
"<price>"+
"536"+
"</price>"+
"</root>";


parser = new DOMParser();
xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(rawxmldoc,"text/xml");
xmlroot = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0];
for (var i = 0; i < xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("price").length; i++)
{
  xmlroot.getElementsByTagName("price")[i].innerHTML *= 32;
  console.log(xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("price")[i].innerHTML);
}
```